# Vue Js : form-data Event

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, multipartform-data

**Hello there**
#Vue.js2
I'm encountering a problem on creating a function called in a *form submit event*
This function needs to take 2 parameters : **EVENT** and **ID**
My problem now is when I call this function i can't specify the event param without having error so my formdata and my id will be **undefined** in my logs.
Is there any better way to handle my form ?

```
 updatePost(event, id) { 
  const postId = id;
  const updatedPost = new FormData(event.target); // Any way to not use event param to save this ? 
  console.log(updatedPost, postId);
},
 // Call in my Template but : 
 <form @submit.prevent="updatePost(post.id)">
```

*ps : form composed by 2 inputs type text and 1 input type file.*[Vue.js screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/370se.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original event is available as `$event` inside the `v-on:` handler.

Docs: [Methods in Inline Handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers)

> *Sometimes we also need to access the original DOM event in an inline statement handler. You can pass it into a method using the special `$event` variable*

So this should work:

```
 <form @submit.prevent="updatePost($event, post.id)">
```